# ng-bootstrap collapse component collapses all components when toggling one - angular 6

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to get more than 1 collapse component on the page, but when you toggle one of them, all of the collapse components get toggled. Is there a way for me to have multiple collapse components to work on 1 page, where i can toggle them individually?

Example: obtained from: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Toggle
  </button>

        <div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    You can collapse this card by clicking Toggle
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample2">
    Toggle
  </button>

        <div id="collapseExample2" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    You can collapse this card by clicking Toggle
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use different model `isCollapsed` on another button click and also on div tag

Comment: What about when you are dynamically generating multiple collapsible forms?

Answer (score 3):

As the OP code looks like it qualified for being generated within a loop, I wanted to provide a more robust solution for dynamically generated content.

The documentation only demonstrated simple case of 1:1 relationship with the model `(isCollapsed)`. If you want to manage hundreds of collapsible this is bad. Instead, as you generate content when iterating over your object, append the collapse state to the object:

`myObjList = [{propKey: propVal, isCollapsed: true}]`

This way you can reference the state by object when the object is interacted with:

`<... *ngFor='let row of myObjList' ...>
    <button class="btn btn-link" (click)="row.isCollapsed = !row.isCollapsed"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
      ` <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample">
              Toggle
           </button>

       <div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                You can collapse this card by clicking Toggle
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-6">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="isCollapsedone = !isCollapsedone" [attr.aria-     expanded]="!isCollapsedone" aria-controls="collapseExample2">
        Toggle
         </button>

      <div id="collapseExample2" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsedone">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                You can collapse this card by clicking Toggle
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

In your typescript:
`public isCollapsedone = false:`

Answer (score 0):

Using the property ngbCollapse has its limitations. Bootstrap was adapted to A more simple solution, that would work in any situations, like yours, where there is no loop over the rows, or other, using loop is as follows:

**Using your code:**

Template (html):

```
<div class="col-6">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" 
           (click)="toggle(collapseExample)"> Toggle
    </button>

    <div #collapseExample >
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                You can collapse this card by clicking Toggle
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

Controller (ts):

```
...
public toggle( element: HTMLElement) {
  element.classList.toggle('d-none');
}
```

**Utilizando ngFor:**

```
...
<tbody *ngFor="let item of items">
  <tr>
   <td class="text-center" (click)="toggle(rowItem)" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr #rowItem>
    Value
  </tr>
</tbody>
```